# Почему оператор сравнения не вызывает перегруженный метод equals?

Tags: kotlin, equals

Я переопределила метод `equals` в классе данных `Point`:

```
data class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
    companion object {
        val TAG = "Kotlin"
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "overrided equals")
        if (other === this) return true
        if (other !is Point) return false
        return other.x == x && other.y == y
    }
}
```

и пытаюсь проверить работу этого метода следующим образом:

```
Log.d(TAG, "${Point(1, 2) == Point(1, 2)}")
Log.d(TAG, "${Point(1, 2) != Point(1, 5)}")
Log.d(TAG, "${null == Point(1, 2)}")
Log.d(TAG, "${Point(1, 2) == null}")
```

Но после выполнения этого кода в консоли получаю:

> overrided equals
>
> true
>
> overrided equals
>
> true
>
> false
>
> false

Из чего следует, что переопределённый метод  `equals` вызывается только для первых двух сравнений. Почему он не вызывается для третьего сравнения, мне тоже понятно (потому что "операторы в Kotlin не поддерживают коммутативность (перемену операндов местами) по умолчанию"). Но я не могу понять, почему переопределённый метод  `equals` не вызывается для последнего, четвёртого сравнения `(Point(1, 2) == null)`...

Ведь значение `null` должно входить в множество типов `Any?`. Например, код

```
val n = null
Log.d(TAG, "null ${if (n is Any?) "is" else "isn't"} type of Any?")
```

возвращает

> null is type of Any?

Следовательно, это сравнение должно подходить под сигнатуру переопределённого метода (`override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean`)...
Почему же переопределённый метод не вызывается для этого сравнения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Kotlin, выражение `a == null`, где `a` переменная, [автоматически переводится](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) в вид `a === null`, также оператор `===` [не может быть переопределён](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

Comment: Да, спасибо, занятно) По второй ссылке нашла даже точный ответ на свой вопрос: "x == null for a non-null x is always false and won't invoke x.equals()."